# How to search a word from inbuilt iOS dictionary programatically?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, dictionary

Is it is possible to search a word from inbuilt iOS dictionary programatically?

`eg`: I have a word say 'apple', and I have to search for the presence of this word in the iOS dictionary.

Can anyone help..?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextChecker_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `UIReferenceLibraryViewController dictionaryHasDefinitionForTerm:` to see if the word exists in the dictionary.